# Using Template Literals with Lodash _.template()

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash, template-literals

I am trying to use template literals with Lodash' `_.template()` to select a message from a JSON file based on a response from another function that determines open/close and it is not working for me.

Flow:

- Function runs logic and returns `open` or `close` via `opencloseResponse.openclose` object (Assumed working and not displayed in my code snippet below)
- Using Lodash `_.template()` I put `messages.open` or `messages.close` with the user's First Name as `first_name`
- Message text is displayed

## Working Example without Template Literal

`messages.json`

```
{
  "messages": {
    "open": "Hello ${ first_name }! We are open!",
    "closed": "Hello ${ first_name }! We are closed!"
  }
}
```

`app.js`

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const { messages } = require('messages.json');

const sendMessage = _.template(messages.open);
console.log(sendMessage({ first_name: 'Jeremy' }));
```

`output`

```
Hello Jeremy! We are open!
```

## Failed Example with Template Literal

`messages.json`

```
{
  "messages": {
    "open": "Hello ${ first_name }! We are open!",
    "closed": "Hello ${ first_name }! We are closed!"
  }
}
```

`app.js`

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const { messages } = require('messages.json');

const sendMessage = _.template(`messages.${opencloseResponse.openclose}`);
console.log(sendMessage({ first_name: 'Jeremy' }));
```

`output`

```
messages.open
```

I'm hoping its something simple that I am missing. It's been driving me nuts all day. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lodash's templates and JavaScript's template literals are completely different animals. If you want to continue to use those JSON files, you wouldn't use JavaScript's template literals, you'd just use dynamic property access:

```
const sendMessage = _.template(messages[opencloseResponse.openclose]);
console.log(sendMessage({ first_name: 'Jeremy' }));
```

If you want to use template literals, the way you make them reusable is to wrap them in *functions*. For instance, instead of your `messages.json`, you might have a `messages.js`:

```
exports.messages = {
  "open": (first_name) => `Hello ${ first_name }! We are open!`,
  "closed": (first_name) => `Hello ${ first_name }! We are closed!`
};
```

then

```
const messages = require('./messages');

console.log(sendMessage(messages[opencloseResponse.openclose]('Jeremy')));
```

Or you could have the function accept an object as with your Lodash code if you preferred:

```
exports.messages = {
  "open": ({first_name}) => `Hello ${ first_name }! We are open!`,
//         ^----------^-------------------------------------------------- destructuring
  "closed": ({first_name}) => `Hello ${ first_name }! We are closed!`
//           ^----------^------------------------------------------------ destructuring
};
```

then

```
const messages = require('./messages');

console.log(sendMessage(messages[opencloseResponse.openclose]({first_name: 'Jeremy'})));
```

Comment: Thank you, TJ. I'll update my question above to remove `await` as that was an artifact me of giving it the 'kitchen sink' try and was not supposed to make it into my question's code. Thank you for providing multiple paths to resolution!

Answer (score 3):

You do not need template literals.

Just use bracket `[]` notation to access the `message` properties

```
const sendMessage = await _.template(messages[opencloseResponse.openclose]);
```